# Send Email issue with SSL

Tags: c#, email, gmail

When I published my website on the internet by free MS Azure, I want to click the button and send a email.

The problem is when I use EnableSsl = true, it give me the error: The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. It may because I used free azure that doesn't support ssl.

When I comment the EnableSsl = true.
It gives me another error:The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.

Any idea for this? Thanks!

Comment: "Must issue a STARTTLS command first" means it not only supports but requires ssl, so you should leave EnableSsl = true. Cannot say anything about authorization though (well it's clear of course that auth is required but don't know much about azure to help you fix that).

Comment: Is your azure site using HTTPS?

Comment: I only have free plan so I cannot use https.

Comment: All plans support HTTPS unless you use a custom domain and do not buy your own certificate. I know that Google has stopped allowing the sending of mail from insecure sites unless you explicitly go into your google account and enable insecure apps. You may be encountering something like that.

Comment: I turned off google secure part. I will try to open https.

Comment: Just add the "s" to "http". It is already turned on for all *.azurewebsites.net sites.

Comment: That's pretty wired. I used https and outlook email account, it works. But it doesn't work for my gmail account. Thanks.